# Creating CLI apps in C

Tags: c

I am wondering how to make a CLI app in C that "constantly runs". What i mean by that us for example i want to just open terminal and type a keyword and a function in a program executes. Like what "ls" is. 
When you type ls it lists contents of the current dir. Likewise i want to make a program that when compiled it executes a certant stuff given the keyword is invoken. I dont want to run the executable with ./example, but rather have the command always available.The compiler i use is gcc. I have read that object file needs to be created but i dont know how to use that.

Thanks

Comment: You just need to see "PATH environment variable".

Comment: Your example does *not* "run constantly". Does `ls` run constantly on your system? Does it need a trigger to show a list of files? The answer to both is "no". When you enter the command `ls`, a suitable executable is *looked up* by your command shell and executed (granted, "built-in commands" are an exception). The difference with your `./example` is mainly that you *tell* what folder to look in – `./ls` will not work in most folders.

Comment: "i want to just open terminal and type a keyword and a function in a program executes".  How else do you use a computer?

Comment: @WilliamPursell lol. I just wanted to make sure no one missunderstood.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Many people — probably the vast majority of people — use computers every day without typing in any commands. They click or tap all day long without ever seeing a shell prompt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What i mean by that us for example i want to just open terminal and type a keyword and a function in a program executes.

Your program doesn't have to "constantly run" in order for you to be able to invoke it without specifying the path... you just have to make sure that the program is located in one of the directories in your PATH, or conversely, that your PATH environment variable includes the directory where your program is located.

So let's say you want to compile `hello.c` into a command called `hello`. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)    
{
  printf("Hello, world!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

So you'd compile that like:

```
> gcc -o hello hello.c
```

Now you should have an executable file called `hello` in your current directory, and you can run it like:

```
> ./hello
```

But you just want to type `hello` anywhere, right? So, you can add the current directory to your PATH environment variable, e.g.:

```
> export PATH=$PATH:$PWD
```

That adds the value of `PWD`, an environment variable that contains the current directory, to `PATH`, which is an environment variable that contains a list of directories where the shell will look for executable programs.

If you want to make that change permanent, you'll need to modify one of the scripts that runs when you start up whatever shell you're using. That's a little beyond the scope of this answer, and there's plenty of advice about how to set up your PATH online, so I'll leave that to you.

Another option, instead of adding the directory that contains `hello` to your PATH, is to move `hello` to one of the directories already listed in PATH. You can see the full list by doing this:

```
> echo $PATH
```

You haven't said what OS you're using, but if it's anything Unix-like there's probably a `/usr/local/bin` listed in there. `.../bin` directories generally hold executable programs, and `/usr/local` is the directory sub-tree where local additions to the OS go. So you could put your program in `/usr/local/bin`, and then (assuming `/usr/local/bin` is in your PATH), `hello` would always be available.

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation. Really helped me out!

Comment: Also, because this always trips people up: do not name your test/example/prototype programs 'test' when using the PATH, because most Unix-like systems already have a program named that.  Make sure your name is unique!